# In python , How to find if a random string (AB122340) lies in between series of strings starting from AB120000 to AB125000

Tags: python

I will get a string from API looks like AB122340, AB122360 .... etc.

I want to return true if that string (AB122340) lies between AB120000 to AB125000

Ex:

for AB122340  --> true

for AB127999  ---> false as it was not in the above range(AB120000 to AB125000)

Comment: have you worked with regex?

Comment: How about just discarding the letters? Maybe after checking they are the same... could they differ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your values are the same length, simple lexical comparison will do. You can use Python's comparison chaining here.

```
if "AB120000" <= the_code <= "AB125000":
```

Or if the range is exclusive (doesn't include its endpoints):

```
if "AB120000" < the_code < "AB125000":
```